Does this inequality holds $ \int_{[0,1]} (f')^2 e^f dx \geq C \int_{[0,1]} f dx$ for some constant $C>0$?
Prove or disprove the following: There exists a universal constant $C>0$ such that
$$ \int_0^1 (f'(x))^2 e^{f(x)}dx \geq C \int_0^1f(x)dx $$
for all $f$ such that $ \int_0^1 e^{-f(x)}dx = 1$.
This question is inspired by log-Sobolev inequalities. I believe it's true but I don't know how to prove this. If there are relevant references, please let me know.

Let $M=\int_0^1{(f’)^2e^f}$.
By Cauchy-Schwarz and your assumption, $$M=\left(\int_0^1{(f’)^2e^f}\right)\left(\int_0^1{e^{-f}}\right) \geq \left(\int_0^1{|f’|}\right)^2.$$
Since $\int_0^1{e^{-f}}=1$ and $f$ is continuous, $f$ vanishes at some point $t \in [0,1]$. Therefore, for any $x \in [0,1]$, $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(t)| \leq \int_0^1{|f’|} \leq \sqrt{M}$.
In particular, $$\int_0^1{f^2} \leq M.$$
Suppose that $M \geq 1$. Then $\int_0^1{f} \leq \left(\int_0^1{f^2}\right)^{1/2} \leq M^{1/2} \leq M$, so the statement works with $C=1$.
From now on assume $M \leq 1$.
Then $|f| \leq 1$ by the above. By Taylor-Lagrange, for $x \in [-1,1]$, one has $|e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}| \leq e\frac{|x|^3}{6}$.
Write $x=-f(t)$ and integrate over $t \in [0,1]$. One has $$\left|-\int_0^1{f}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{f^2}\right| \leq \frac{e}{6}\int_0^1{|f|^3} \leq \frac{e}{6}\int_0^1{|f|^2},$$ whence $$\int_0^1{f} \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{e}{6}\right)\int_0^1{f^2} \leq \int_0^1{f^2} \leq M,$$ and $C=1$ still works.

Hello, thanks for your answer. There is no square on the right hand side of my ineq. From your last inequality, we can only say $M \geq \Big( \int_0^1 f  \Big)^2$ and $x^2 \geq x$ is not guaranteed...

Oh, good point. Let me think about how to fix this…

I think this works now?

I think everything is correct now, I couldn't detect any mistake at the moment. +1 for this nice proof!  (I'm not the one who downvoted, seems like there are people who want to downvote without caring to comment the reason why...)
